Identity server 4 redirect when project removed
In the past I have sued identity server 4 as the identity provider. Now, i have deleted the identity project from my solution, removed every mention on the identity url from my solution and also implementing identity with asp.net core identity. But something strange is happening; after the login operation has a valid response, I am redirecting the user into the main application. From the server, I get first a 302 status code and then I am redirected to the link which was used through identity server 4 (localhost:1234/Account/Login/RedirectUrl/%F....etc). The client is under a web spa project. Honestly, I don't know where to look anymore since I have removed every use of identity server 4 from the solution.

"and also implementing identity with asp.net core identity." - IdentityServer and ASP.NET Identity are not substitutable: they do different things.

Your post does not tell us what is going wrong

Maybe it's a cache problem. Or something in the database. Have you checked you app file config?
